# iOS viewDidLoad is not calling

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

Hi i am facing problem

I have navigation base iPad app , now i created two login.h, login.m,login.xib and registration.h ,registration.m, registration.xib , In my login.xib i have a button register , when i am clicking on this button registration , then object is created and initWithNibName is called of the registration class but nib is not loading .

My code is:

```
Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registation" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];
```

Please help me.

Comment: u added UINavigationController ?

Comment: Amit Patel: Yes i added UINavigationController

Comment: -(IBAction)btnRegisterClicked:(id)sender
{
    Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];  
}

Comment: are you sure the connection is made with IBOutlet? Put an NSLog to insure that the action method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your code and then post the resulting log:

```
NSLog(@"Self: %@, NavController: %@, Registration: %@", self, self.navigationController, registration);
```

I'm gonna guess that somehow your self.navigationController is going to be (null) and that's why the view is not loading.

Comment: Thank's , Yes
 i found navigation controller object is null ,then i added 
 navigationCntrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationCntrl; but when i am ruuning my app it appears black screen

Comment: I am getting Black window after creating navigation bar object

Comment: Great! Glad I could help, and well done solving your black screen problem.

Answer (score 0):

use ...

```
Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc] init];
```

instad of

```
Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registation" bundle:nil];
```

**OR**

**Check your IBAction of Register Button in File's Owner , properly set or not ????**

may be help full for you :)

Comment: i am check all wairing with IBOutlet

Comment: can you give me you please share ur skype id

Comment: In Login.m : -(IBAction)btnRegisterClicked:(id)sender
{
    Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];  
}

Comment: every time initWithNib is Called of Registration.m but viewDidLoad is Not called

Comment: @Jack- ur code is correct .nothing is false ...please check BUTTON at set **file's owner** set an IBAction set `UITouch Up Inside` and check  both files of components at file's owner :)

Comment: i checked ..evry thing is okay.. but still i am getting same error

Comment: @Jack- `[registration release];` use in code ...generally it is not create any problem but may be .....